# [UIRemoteKeyboardWindow release]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios

I've tried multiple variations of this,but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?
crash in auto release pool.

Crash log:

2016-11-25 10:34:44.659 DHOTT[60818:1388887] [DEBUG][2016/11/25 10:34:44.659422]has UIRemoteKeyboardWindow > at DHToast.m:190 lines

2016-11-25 10:34:44.662 DHOTT[60818:1382729] *** -[UIRemoteKeyboardWindow release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7c555c00

(lldb) po 0x7c555c00
2016-11-25 10:38:03.920 DHOTT[60818:1382729] *** -[UIRemoteKeyboardWindow respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7c555c00

Crash stack:

```
Incident Identifier: F7B960B4-C2CD-4FDE-8851-7678AF5C6CFA
CrashReporter Key:   767929adc7679416f668cc342d827b3c4cc1e57d
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,2
Process:              [799]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/FFF13FF6-19C7-4A65-8447-F1983064C685/
Identifier:          com.dada.dh.share
Version:             20161107152706 (1.0.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-11-07 16:16:07.07 +0800
Launch Time:         2016-11-07 15:34:04.04 +0800
OS Version:          iOS 9.2 (13C75)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
47.145841    AppleJPEG                  0x00000001828d4ff4 [0x160182c00] Decoding completed without errors
47.147908    AppleJPEG                  0x00000001828d318c [0x60182c00] Options: 1x148 [000000DA,FFFFFFFF] FFFFFFFF
47.147908    AppleJPEG                  0x00000001828d3044 [0x160182c00] Decoding: C0 0x009400DA 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 5137
47.149789    AppleJPEG                  0x00000001828d2338 [0x160182c00] Created session
47.294822    AppleJPEG                  0x00000001828d4ff4 [0x160047000] Decoding completed without errors
47.295489    AppleJPEG                  0x00000001828d318c [0x160047000] Options: 132x99 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
47.295489    AppleJPEG                  0x00000001828d3044 [0x160047000] Decoding: C0 0x00840063 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 3512
47.296253    AppleJPEG                  0x00000001828d2338 [0x60047000] Created session
48.979907    AppleJPEG                  0x00000001828d4ff4 [0x160272c00] Decoding completed without errors
48.980227    AppleJPEG                  0x00000001828d318c [0x160272c00] Options: 400x225 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
48.980227    AppleJPEG                  0x00000001828d3044 [0x160272c00] Decoding: C0 0x019000E1 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 11482
48.980228    AppleJPEG                  0x00000001828d4ff4 [0x160284c00] Decoding completed without errors
48.981071    AppleJPEG                  0x00000001828d318c [UNSUP] Options: 23078988x-1879048192 [E1000001,FF000000] FFFFFFFF



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001808edbd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811593e0 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 152
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001808f5ae8 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 508
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018115142c _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181222a20 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181151680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
6   GraphicsServices                0x0000000182660088 GSEventRunModal + 180
7   UIKit                           0x0000000185fc8d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
8   DHOTT                           0x00000001002e286c main (main.m:16)
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000180cf28b8 start + 4
```

Comment: message sent to deallocated instance means that, you're calling any method (message) on a particular object which has already been deallocated from memory. Could you give more code snippet so we can see what's going wrong?

Comment: Uiremotekeyboardwindow is a system keyboard. Our code did not use it directly, just add dialog and a textflied. And this crash probably happen after dialog dismiss .

Comment: These kind of crashes may be caused by 3rd party SDKs too. True story.

Comment: How to fix it and why?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei which sdk， can you tell me, thanks!

Comment: @user1676925, I can't remember exactly, but Crittercism and Flurry for example seem to cause some crashes.

Answer (score 0):

you can eidt your scheme, check the diagnostics->Zombie Objects.
Then ,repeat your crash ,in console you will see which object was release.

Comment: [UIRemoteKeyboardWindow release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7c555c00

Comment: then, you can po this adress, see which object was release

Comment: (lldb) po 0x7c555c00 2016-11-25 10:38:03.920 DHOTT[60818:1382729] *** -[UIRemoteKeyboardWindow respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7c555c00